# Reuse Subquery from Select Expression in WHERE-Clause

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

Of course it isn't possible to write

```
SELECT (some subselect) AS blah FROM t WHERE blah = 'const'
```

What is the best way to do this?

- `SELECT (some subselect) FROM t WHERE (some subselect) = 'const'`?
- View?
- Stored Function?
- HAVING?
- other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can move `(some subselect)` as table in the `FROM` :

```
SELECT s.blah
  FROM t, (some subselect) s
 WHERE t.id = s.id
   AND s.blah = 'const'
```

Comment: but then you'd have to give up the `join on` syntax and use the dirty `where` join syntax?

Comment: Why is that? you can always use both (`s` is a table on its own). And why `where` is dirty? it's also a join (cross join) and can be useful.